# Passing data to leaflet from ag-grid programmitically

Tags: javascript, leaflet, ag-grid

I am a total javascript/leaflet/ag-grid newbie, so please bear with me.

I am creating a website that allows users to query (add/remove) spatial points on a leaflet map based on selecting rows from ag-grid. I have no understanding/experience with React or Angular, so I am using vanilla javascript. Leaflet is used to display the data spatially.

I have spatial data that has GPS coordinates that are parent records. Each parent they have multiple children.

## Spatial data

The spatial data is an external file I read into my HTML file. It looks like this:

```
var spatial_data = {
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", 
"properties": { "Name": "Boulder 1", "SpatialID": "Lower Blair_0" }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -105.39079766, 41.19044516, 2510.159912109375 ] } },

{ "type": "Feature", 
"properties": { "Name": "Boulder 2", "SpatialID": "Upper Blair_1" }, 
"geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ -105.39058423, 41.19655902, 2534.4599609375 ] } }
]};
```

### Children records

There are children records for each parent spatial ID. The data is within the .js code.

The functionality I am hoping for is someone could filter the ag-grid for a route called 'Slam Dunk' and that would provide the "SpatialID":"Lower Blair_0". If they filter for 'Test two' it provides the same SpatialID. This would be available to play around within the HTML file.

#### myownscript.js

```
var rowData = [{"Route Name":"Slam Dunk","SpatialID":"Lower Blair_0"},
 {"Route Name":"Test two","SpatialID":"Lower Blair_0"},
 {"Route Name":"Test three","SpatialID":"Upper Blair_1"}];

var columnDefs= [
    {field: 'Route Name', minWidth:10, sortable:true, filter:true},
    {field: 'Sub-Area', minWidth:5, sortable:true, filter:true},       
];

const gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    rowData: rowData,
    defaultColDef:{
        flex:1,
        minWidth:100
    },
    rowSelection: 'multiple',
    pagination:true
};

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
};

function grabFilteredData(){
    let rowData = [];
    gridOptions.api.forEachNodeAfterFilter(node => {
        rowData.push(node.data.SpatialID);
    });
    
    var uniqueID = rowData.filter(onlyUnique);
    
    return uniqueID;
}


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const gridDiv = document.querySelector('#myGrid');
    new agGrid.Grid(gridDiv, gridOptions);

});
```

I can easily send 'test' to the console. That provides me with the ability to check that my `onSelectionChanged()` is working; however, I really need to pass the output from `onSelectionChanged()` as an array. I need to pass that and use that in an embedded script within my HTML. This is so I can filter the data in my leaflet layers and features.

### my html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
   
    <!-- Read in the geojson-->
    <script src='assets/spatialdata.json'></script>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community@27.0.1/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
    <script src="myownscript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <script >
        
var sat_data = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
          attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
          maxZoom: 18,
          id: 'mapbox/satellite-streets-v11',
          tileSize: 512,
          zoomOffset: -1,
          accessToken: 'my.api.key'
});

var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(new L.LatLng(41.008,-106.710), new L.LatLng(41.813,-104.861));   

var baseMaps = {
    "Satellite":sat_data
};

      var map = L.map('map', {
        center: [41.210, -105.360],
        zoom: 11,
        layers:[osm,sat_data],
        noWrap:true,
        maxBounds:bounds,
        maxBoundsViscosit:1.0
      });

      L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
  
      var promise = $.getJSON("/assets/vedauwoo.geojson");
      promise.then(function(data){
          var allData = L.geoJson(data,{
            onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                  layer.bindPopup('<h4> Area Name: '+feature.properties.Name+'</h4><p>Grades: '+feature.properties.Grade+'</p>');
                }
          });
          var others = L.geoJson(data, {
              onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                  layer.bindPopup('<h4> Area Name: '+feature.properties.Name+'</h4><p>Grades: '+feature.properties.Grade+'</p>');
                },
              filter: function(feature,layer){

              }
          });
          var layerGroup = L.layerGroup().addTo(map);
          allData.addTo(layerGroup)

          $("#others").click(function() {
            
            var dataToSubset = grabFilteredData();
         
            var subset_data = L.geoJson(data, {
              onEachFeature: function(feature,layer){
                  layer.bindPopup('<h4> Area Name: '+feature.properties.Name+'</h4><p>Grades: '+feature.properties.Grade+'</p>');
                },
              filter: function(feature,layer){
                  return dataToSubset.includes(feature.properties.SpatialID);
              }
            });
            //Works in a hacky way by sending the ID over
            layerGroup.removeLayer(allData)  
            layerGroup.addLayer(subset_data)
            window.map_id = subset_data._leaflet_id;
          });
          $("#allData").click(function() {
            layerGroup.removeLayer(map_id)
            layerGroup.addLayer(allData)
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried extensive searching. For some reason, the majority of use cases for `gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()` or `forEachNodeAfterFilter` end with an example of using console.log(). I need to actually pass that information along instead of just outputting to the console. I am not sure if this is a misunderstanding on my part for how JS works, or if it is expected behavior from ag-grid, but it doesn't seem possible.

This doesn't seem to work as the console.log() in the .js file doesn't work, and in the script in the HTML it can not find test.

I am primarily a statistician/python programmer, so this a new foray for me. It is likely I am missing a bigger picture thing and if so, I would appreciate alternatives to my current approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So once `onSelectionChanged` is called with the filtered rows - what script do you need to pass it to?

I assume you want to link the table with the leaflet map. If so, you need to

- obtain a reference to the map object (see [Leaflet docs](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#map-example))
- create a [GeoJSON layer](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) based on the filtered Geometries and add it to the map.

If the filtering in the table and thus the leaflet layer data update happens multiple times, you need to remove the existing layer and add a new one, as far as I know. Check this post.

Comment: Hi Geo. Thank you for answering. I need to pass the filtered rows to a script embedded in the html that creates a GeoJSON layer based on filtering Geometries. That part I have done. I can not get the filtered data from my external .js file to my .html file. I do want to link my table to leaflet, but my problem is 'grabbing' the data exported from my onSelectionChanged.

Comment: So that external script is leaflet, correct?

Comment: What you need is a script that has the map object in scope (e.g. by attaching it to the global window object), sets up the logic to update layer data and exposed that as a function which can then be used in myownscript.js

Comment: My external script has all of the ag-grid functionality. My internal script, within my HTML, has all of the leaflet definitions and functionality. I can't seem to edit my original question for some reason, but if I could I think I could clear that up. 

If you are saying that I need to combine into one .js file: leaflet + ag-grid, I did try that. The issue I am having is the onSelectionChanged() function. I need to return the information from that function to leaflet.

Comment: Mh, hard to explain it now. If you upload the code to a GitHub repo or email me a zip I can check it out and build a minimum solution to show what I meant with my earlier comment

Comment: Hi Geo. I edited my original question now. It should all work out of the box except for the lack of an API key for mapbox. I ended up trying to simplify things a bit. But in my edited question I am using `forEachNodeAfterFilter` in myownscript.js. I can call that function in the code within my HTML. But it is giving me some odd errors.

It seems like I need to add an EventListener for the DOMContentLoaded before I try and filter the spatial data. The error I am getting is an 'undefined'.

I have the code on GitHub: https://github.com/jlombard314159/vedauwooBouldering

Comment: Sorry to double comment. I updated my post again. I am really close but not 100% there. 

In $("#others") I can now subset to whatever I filtered to, but only once. Additionally, I can't remove the layer from $("#allData"). So getting there but not 100% I am doing things correctly.

Comment: 1. You need to use gridApi.getSelectedNodes() to get the table selection (https://blog.ag-grid.com/how-to-get-the-data-of-selected-rows-in-ag-grid/)

Comment: Raised a PR https://github.com/jlombard314159/vedauwooBouldering/pull/1